# Find the 10001st prime number (in C++)

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wrote this solution for project Euler #7, to find the 10001th prime number using sieve of eratosthenes. It's really slow though. Any suggestions to improve performance (without using more complex sieves like sieve of atkin)?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<climits>
#define max 500000
using namespace  std;


int main()
{
 int ctr = 0;
 int i=2,j,n=10001,p=2;
 int arr[max];
 memset(arr,0,sizeof(arr));
 while(1)
 {

 p=2;
 while(p*p<=i)
 {

  if(arr[p] == 0)
     for(j=p*p;j<=i;j+=p)
        arr[j] = 1;

        p++;

    }
   if(arr[i]==0)
    ctr++;
   if(ctr==n)
    break;
   i++;

  }

 cout<<i;

 }
```

Comment: It causes stack overflow on windows, VC++14.

Comment: I used code blocks ,windows   and it worked all right.

Comment: I'm not saying the code is broken, just saying that on VC++14 it might fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Why is everybody using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`? It is so hard to include `<cstring>` to get `memset` working?
- Why do you need `<climits>`?
- Don't use `using namespace std;`. It's a bad practice.
- Static array of `int`s with size `500000` is likely too big to fit into stack. Use `int * arr = new int[max]` and `delete [] arr;` instead.
- Using whole integers to store boolean value is just a waste of memory.
- It takes 42 seconds to find result. My version (without sieve) takes about real: 0.015s, user: 0.013s.

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  bool isPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= num; ++i) {
      if ((num % i) == 0) return false;
    }
    return num > 1;
  }

  int main() {
    int i = 2;
    for (int primes = 0; ; ++i) {
      if (isPrime(i)) {
        if (++primes == 10001) {
          std::cout << i << "\n";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks , i tried it without sieve and got similar results

Answer (score 0):

If the prime number to be found is always going to be the 10001st prime number, then you can greatly improve the performance by hard-coding the result:

```
#include <iostream>
#define PRIME_10001 104743

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << PRIME_10001 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If `104743` is banned for some reason, here are some alternatives:

- `0x19927` in base 16,
- `0314447` in octal,
- `0b11001100100100111` in binary with C++14 (or GNU C),
- `104'743` with a C++14 digit separator

If you do use the `for`-loop approach mentioned in [the previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/136344), you should note that the condition of this loop may overflow:

```
for (int i = 2; i*i <= num /* for i as little as 256: kaboom! */; ++i) {
```

Instead, using division eliminates several possibilities:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= num/i; ++i) {
```

You should probably use an `unsigned` integer to remove the rest of the possibilities for overflow. Alternatively, check if `num` is negative and return `false` if it is.