# Prime Sieve and brute force #2

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Based on my previous attempt.

[Prime Sieve and brute force](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221678/507)

Trying to make the interface simpler I have moved all the code into a class. This way I can keep track of the `primes` and `inc` and the `next` value to look at. This way I can control accesses to `isPrime()` so it can not be called on values directly (as it makes the assumption you have already calculated all previous primes).

When my code is manipulating a potential prime it uses `int` as the type. If the code is working on the size of a container or index into a container directly then I use `std::size_t`.

I tried being consistent with my braces. But an `if` statement that just had a return inside looked so ugly with my standard braces.

```
if (<test>)
{
    return;
}
// I know it only saves one line but that looks ugly and wasteful
if (<test>) {
    return;
}
```

So I have kept them small but otherwise open/closing braces are aligned on the left.

#### se.h

```
#ifndef THORSANVIL_UTIL_SIEVE_ERATOSTHENES_H
#define THORSANVIL_UTIL_SIEVE_ERATOSTHENES_H

#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstddef>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{

class SieveEratosthenes
{
    public:
    using Primes = std::vector<int>;

    private:
    static std::size_t constexpr maxSieveSize = 1024 * 1024;// approx 1M
    Primes  primes;
    int     inc;
    int     next;

    public:
        SieveEratosthenes(int nTh);
        Primes const& thePrimes()   const {return primes;}
        int           count()       const {return primes.size();}
        int           getCurrent()  const {return primes.back();}
        int           getNext()           {calcNext(); return getCurrent();}
    private:
        void          calcNext();
        bool          isPrime(int num);
        int           getNextInc()        {inc = 6 - inc;return inc;}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, SieveEratosthenes const& data)
        {   
            for(auto prime: data.primes) {
                str << prime << " ";
            }   
            return str;
        }   
};

}

#endif
```

### se.cpp

```
#include "se.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace ThorsAnvil;

SieveEratosthenes::SieveEratosthenes(int nTH)
    : inc(4)
    , next(5)
{
    // We know we will have `nTH` primes.
    primes.reserve(nTH);

    // Take care of people trying to be silly and break things.
    if (nTH <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    primes.emplace_back(2);
    if (nTH == 1) {
        return;
    }
    primes.emplace_back(3);
    if (nTH == 2) {
        return;
    }   

    // Estimate the sieve size we will need to find the `nth` prime.
    // This is not exact so it will get you most of the way there.
    // But this means you will have to brute force the rest.
    // See the last loop in the constructor for that.
    std::size_t sieveSize = nTH * std::log(nTH) / 2;  // Note: div 2 because we don't hold even numbers
    sieveSize = std::min(sieveSize, maxSieveSize / sizeof(typename Primes::value_type) * CHAR_BIT);

    // primeCandidates holds true/false for each potential prime candidate.
    // The index represents the potential prime (index * 2 + 1)
    // This allows us to ignore all multiple of 2
    // max is one past the highest prime candidate we can test for and store in primeCandidates
    std::vector<bool>   primeCandidates(sieveSize, true);

    // We will use the technique of incrementing by 2 then 4 then 2 then 4
    // This means skip all multiple of 2 and 3 automatically.
    for(; next < sieveSize && nTH != count(); next += getNextInc())
    {       
        std::size_t index = next/2;

        // If we find a candidate that is valid then add it to results.
        if (primeCandidates[index])
        {
            primes.push_back(next);

            // Now strain out all multiple of the prime we just found.
            for(index = next * next / 2; index < primeCandidates.size(); index += next)
            {
                primeCandidates[index] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    while(nTH != count())
    {
        calcNext();
    }
}

void SieveEratosthenes::calcNext()
{
    while(!isPrime(next))
    {
        next += getNextInc();
    }
    primes.push_back(next);
    next += getNextInc();
}

bool SieveEratosthenes::isPrime(int num)
{
    // Note: All primes less than num have already been found and stored in
    //       the container `primes`. So this can only be used as part of
    //       a brute force attack where you iterate up the number space and
    //       store any found primes in `prime`. See: calcNext()
    int max = std::sqrt(num);
    for(auto const& prime: primes)
    {
        if (prime > max) {
            return true;
        }
        if (num % prime == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### main.cpp

Just a test to hang things from:

```
#include "se.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    try
    {
        int find; 
        if ((argc != 2) || ((find = std::stoi(argv[1])) < 1))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Arguments");
        }

        using SE = ThorsAnvil::SieveEratosthenes;
        SE  sieve(find);

        std::cout << find << " prime: " << sieve.getCurrent() << "\n"
                  << sieve << "\n";
    }   
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        throw;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: Unknown Type\n";
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Our coding guidelines allow `if (<test>) return;` (but just in case of `return`, nothing else, e.g. not `i++`). That's the [return early](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18459/109304) pattern. I'd personally not use it in general, but for Desktop C++ it's fine. May not be fine in embedded C++ environment where you have limited breakpoints

Answer (score 4):

At first, I was surprised by the use of a class here, but having read the code (and especially the `main()`), it clearly makes sense.  It might be possible to make it more natural to use by providing a (const) iterator to access the values, rather than the `getCurrent()`/`getNext()` interface.

Consider defining the streaming operator in the implementation file.  Not a big deal for this small program, but in well-used classes, it can make a difference, by allowing the header to include `<iosfwd>` instead of `<ostream>`.  The former is intended to be faster for compilation.

A missing include in the implementation file: `<climits>` is required, for `CHAR_BIT`.

The class delegates all its resource management, smoothly satisfying the Rule of Zero.  `:-)`

I don't see why we accept (signed) `int` as argument, if we're not allowing negative numbers.  There's a serious bug anyway, in that we `reserve(nTH)` before we know it's not negative.

`-Weffc++` warns about the default-initialised `primes` member.  It's good to be explicit, and in this case it can simplify the constructor a little:

```
SieveEratosthenes::SieveEratosthenes(int nTH)
    : inc(4)
    , next(5)
    , primes{2, 3}
{
    // Take care of people trying to be silly and break things.
    if (nTH <= 0) {
        primes.clear()
        return;
    }
    if (nTH <= 2) {
        primes.resize(nTH);
        return;
    }

    // We know we will have `nTH` primes.
    primes.reserve(nTH);
```

`std::vector<bool>` optimises space at the expense of speed.  We may find that `std::vector<char>` is more performant for reasonable sizes - have you done any benchmarks to justify this choice?